# Uninstalling on-premise exchange 2007 after outsourcing

Tags: exchange-server, uninstallation, exchange-server-2007, hosted

We have recently migrated a single server exchange 2007 organisation out to a hosted exchange platform and everyone is working fine against the new platform.

The question I have is a simple one really.

Should I go through the process of properly uninstalling the exchange organisation from the server that it is on or should I just turn the server off. Presently the box is still on, albeit with all of the exchange services stopped.

I read that uninstalling the exchange organisation won't remove the objects/attributes that are added to the AD so is there any benefit of removing the organisation opposed to just turning off the server. Will there be any issues down the line with AD if I don't uninstall, and anything to be aware of if I did uninstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend turning the box off and take a backup of the hdd if later issues would occur (which propably won't because, as you say, all services are stopped). After these steps, you can format or do whatever you want to it.

Comment: Thanks.. That is my preferred option (less work and less scope for issues during uninstall!), just wondering if there are any potential issues in a few months with tombstoning the dead server. I'm in no rush to reprovision the server into a new role, so may just pull it out of the rack and leave it to one side for a few months.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. If the backup is taken successfully, you should always be able to go back to your 'old' environment. Or as you suggest, just leave the server aside as a backup.